# Aplicação esta retornando erro NullPointerException apesar do objeto estar definido

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Erro ao clicar em salvar o novo processo após atribuir os dados em cada campo:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long com.example.alex.levprocess.processos.RepositorioProcesso.salvar(com.example.alex.levprocess.processos.Processo)' on a null object reference 
at com.example.alex.levprocess.processos.NovoProcesso.salvarProcesso(NovoProcesso.java:76)
at com.example.alex.levprocess.processos.NovoProcesso.salvar(NovoProcesso.java:69)
at com.example.alex.levprocess.processos.NovoProcesso$2.onClick(NovoProcesso.java:45)
```

**Classe NovoProcesso**

```
package com.example.alex.levprocess.processos;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import com.example.alex.levprocess.R;
import com.example.alex.levprocess.cliente.MenuCliente;

public class NovoProcesso extends Activity {

private EditText nome, responsavel, papel, objetivo, condicao, entradas, saidas, roteiro;
private Long id;

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.novo_processo);
    nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNomeProcesso);
    responsavel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etResponsavel);
    papel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPapel);
    objetivo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etObjetivo);
    condicao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCondicao);
    entradas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEntradas);
    saidas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSaidas);
    roteiro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRoteiro);
    id = null;
    ImageButton btCancelar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btCancelar);
    Button cdsRoteiro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoRoteiro);

    btCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            finish();// Fecha a tela
        }
    });
    ImageButton btSalvar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btSalvar);
    btSalvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            salvar();
        }
    });
}
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Cancela para nao ficar nada na tela pendente
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    // Fecha a tela
    finish();
}
public void salvar() {
    Processo processo = new Processo();
    if (id != null) {
        processo.id = id;// E uma atualizacao
    }
    processo.nome = nome.getText().toString();
    processo.responsavel = responsavel.getText().toString();
    processo.papel = papel.getText().toString();
    processo.objetivo = objetivo.getText().toString();
    processo.condicao = condicao.getText().toString();
    processo.entradas = entradas.getText().toString();
    processo.saidas = saidas.getText().toString();
    processo.roteiro = roteiro.getText().toString();
    salvarProcesso(processo);// Salvar
    setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent()); // OK
    // Fecha a tela
    finish();
}

protected void salvarProcesso(Processo processo) {
    CadastroProcessos.repositorio.salvar(processo);
}

}
```

**Dados da Classe RepositorioProcesso**

```
public long salvar(Processo processo) {
long id = processo.id;
if (id != 0) {
    atualizar(processo);
} else {
    // Insere novo
    id = inserir(processo);
}
return id;
}

// Insere um novo processo
public long inserir(Processo processo) {
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Processos.NOME, processo.nome);
values.put(Processos.RESPONSAVEL, processo.responsavel);
values.put(Processos.PAPEL, processo.papel);
values.put(Processos.OBJETIVO, processo.objetivo);
values.put(Processos.CONDICAO, processo.condicao);
values.put(Processos.ENTRADAS, processo.entradas);
values.put(Processos.SAIDAS, processo.saidas);
values.put(Processos.ROTEIRO, processo.roteiro);
long id = inserir(values);
return id;
}
// Insere um novo processo
public long inserir(ContentValues valores) {
long id = db.insert(NOME_TABELA, "", valores);
return id;
}
```

**Classe CadastroProcesso**

```
import java.util.List;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.alex.levprocess.R;
import com.example.alex.levprocess.processos.Processo.Processos;

public class CadastroProcessos extends ListActivity {
  protected static final int INSERIR_EDITAR = 1;
  protected static final int BUSCAR = 2;
  public static RepositorioProcesso repositorio;
    private List<Processo> processos;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
      super.onCreate(icicle);
      repositorio = new RepositorioProcesso(this);
      atualizarLista();
}
protected void atualizarLista() {
    // Pega a lista de processos e exibe na tela
    processos = repositorio.listarProcessos();
    // Adaptador de lista customizado para cada linha de um processo
    setListAdapter(new ProcessoListAdapter(this, processos));
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, INSERIR_EDITAR, 0, "Inserir Novo").setIcon(R.drawable.novo);
    menu.add(0, BUSCAR, 0, "Buscar").setIcon(R.drawable.pesquisar);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    // Clicou no menu
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case INSERIR_EDITAR:
            // Abre a tela com o formulario para adicionar
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, EditarProcesso.class),        INSERIR_EDITAR);
            break;
        case BUSCAR:
            // Abre a tela para buscar o processo pelo nome
            startActivity(new Intent(this, BuscarProcesso.class));
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int posicao, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, posicao, id);
    editarProcesso(posicao);
}
// Recupera o id do processo, e abre a tela de edicao
protected void editarProcesso(int posicao) {
    // Usuario clicou em algum processo da lista e
    // Recupera o processo selecionado
    Processo processo = processos.get(posicao);
    // Cria a intent para abrir a tela de editar
    Intent it = new Intent(this, EditarProcesso.class);
    // Passa o id do processo como parametro
    it.putExtra(Processos._ID, processo.id);
    // Abre a tela de edicao
    startActivityForResult(it, INSERIR_EDITAR);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int codigo, int codigoRetorno, Intent it) {
    super.onActivityResult(codigo, codigoRetorno, it);
    // Quando a activity EditarCurriculo retornar, seja se foi para adicionar vamos atualizar a lista
    if (codigoRetorno == RESULT_OK) {
        // atualiza a lista na tela
        atualizarLista();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Fecha o banco
    repositorio.fechar();
}
}
```

Comment: A linha 76 informada no erro é essa:  CadastroProcessos.repositorio.salvar(processo);

Comment: Olá, Alex. Coloque o código da classe CadastroProcesso.

Comment: Possível duplicada de [Retornando objeto nulo quando efetuo um cadastro no banco de dados](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100841/retornando-objeto-nulo-quando-efetuo-um-cadastro-no-banco-de-dados).

Comment: A Retornando objeto removi pelos erros de formatação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que eu encontrei foi:

Declarar o RepositorioProcesso do tipo private em cada classe:

```
private RepositorioProcesso repositorio;
```

Sempre inicializar ele no onCreate de cada classe:

```
repositorio = new RepositorioProcesso(this);
```

E na linha 76 da classe NovoProcesso, que estava escrita da seguinte forma:

```
protected void salvarProcesso(Processo processo) {
  CadastroProcessos.repositorio.salvar(processo);
}
```

Substituir pelo código abaixo:

```
protected void salvarProcesso(Processo processo) {
    repositorio.salvar(processo);
}
```

**Com esse ajuste a aplicação rodou corretamente sem erro**

Answer (score 2):

`CadastroProcesso` é uma Activity. Você está mexendo numa variável dela através de outra Activity. Isso é extremamente não recomendado em Android. O mesmo vale para membros estáticos de Activities.

No seu caso específico, a variável `repositorio` não existe no instante que você tentou acessá-la porque nunca foi criado um exemplar da classe `CadastroProcesso`. Quando você quer que uma tela faça algo, você passa uma mensagem para ela através de um Bundle na hora da criação (ou como resposta para a tela que a chamou).

Você precisa repensar o funcionamento da sua aplicação.